# Android actionbar loses style when viewed in recent apps

Tags: android, android-actionbar

When using the recent apps button in Android the action bar of my app does not retain its style like other apps do.  The action bar color returns to the default gray and the text to the default black.  Does anyone know how to control this behavior in an Android project?

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated.